# Update records using signals in Django

Tags: django, django-models

I have created 2 models:

1. `Logs` stores log of every entry;
2. `LogFeeds` gets the count of all the entries above comparing the actor, verb and date.

How can I update my second model from the first model using signals?

```
class Logs(models.Model):
    actor_content_type = models.ForeignKey(ContentType,related_name='actor')
    actor_object_id = models.PositiveIntegerField() 
    actor = generic.GenericForeignKey('actor_content_type','actor_object_id')
    verb = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    description = models.TextField(blank=True,null=True)
    target_content_type = models.ForeignKey(ContentType,related_name='target',blank=True,null=True)
    target_object_id = models.PositiveIntegerField(blank=True,null=True) 
    target = generic.GenericForeignKey('target_content_type','target_object_id')
    object_content_type = models.ForeignKey(ContentType,blank=True,null=True)
    object_object_id = models.PositiveIntegerField(blank=True,null=True) 
    object = generic.GenericForeignKey('object_content_type','object_object_id')
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    public = models.BooleanField(default=True)

class LogFeeds(models.Model):
    actors_content_type = models.ForeignKey(ContentType,related_name='actors')
    actors_object_id = models.PositiveIntegerField() 
    actors = generic.GenericForeignKey('actors_content_type','actors_object_id')
    verbs = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    descriptions = models.TextField(blank=True,null=True)
    targets_content_type = models.ForeignKey(ContentType,related_name='targets',blank=True,null=True)
    targets = generic.GenericForeignKey('targets_content_type',)
    objects_content_type = models.ForeignKey(ContentType,blank=True,null=True)
    objects_object_id = models.PositiveIntegerField(blank=True,null=True) 
    objects = generic.GenericForeignKey('objects_content_type','objects_object_id')
    logs = models.ManyToManyField(Logs)
```

Comment: What do you want to achieve?

Comment: @Krzysiek Szularz  i want to combine individual activity feed from Logs into LogFeeds. comparing the actor, verb, and timestamp(only date). and display it as one record in Logfeeds.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure, what you need it for.

If you want to log something in you code, look at [sentry](https://github.com/getsentry/sentry) project. You set it up as a handler and use it with normal Django logging system.

If you want to re-invent the wheel I have some advices:

First, you don't need to have `ManyToManyField` for logs. I presume `Log` can have only one `LogFeed`. Use `ForeignKey` from `Log` to `LogFeeds` instead.

Then the code could look like:

```
def log(actor, target, object):
    now, today = …

    feed = (LogFeed.objects.select_for_update()
                   .get_or_create(actor=actor, 
                                  target=target, 
                                  object=object,
                                  date=today))
    Log.objects.create(feed=feed,
                       verb='Something happened',
                       timestamp=now)
```

Indeed it could be invoked on `post_save` signal each instance you're interested in sends.

See the related [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/signals/) for examples on how to use signals in Django.